# How to store the result of a SQL statement as a variable and use the result in an SSIS Expression?

Tags: ssis, expression

I am using a `SSIS` `Data Flow Task` to transfer data from one table to another. Column A in Table A contains a number, the last 3 digits of which I want to store in Column B of Table B.

First I'm trying to grab all of the data in Column A and store in a variable via a simple `SELECT` statement `SELECT COLUMN_A FROM TABLE_A`. However, the variable stores the statement as a string when I want the result set of the query. I have set the `EvaluateAsExpression` property to `False` but to no avail.

Secondly I want to be able to use the result of this query in the `Derived Column` of my `Data Flow` to extract the last 3 digits and store the values in Column_B in the destination. The expression I have is:

`(DT_STR,3,1252)RIGHT(@User::[VariableName],3)`

I want to store this as a string hence the `(DT_STR,3,1252)` data type.

All I'm getting so far in Column_B of Table_B is is the last 3 characters of the `SELECT` statement "E_A". There is a lot of useful information on the web including YouTube videos for things like setting file paths and server names as parameters or variables but I can't see many relevant to the specifics of my query.

I have used an `Execute SQL Task` to insert row counts from flat files but, in this example, I want to use the `Derived Column` tool instead.

What am i doing wrong? Any help is gratefully appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks KeithL thats one solution I will use in future but I found another.

I dropped the variable and in the `Expression` box of the `Transformation Editor` did:

`(DT_STR,3,1252)RIGHT((DT_STR,3,1252)Column_A,3)`.

In my question, I failed to cast Column_A from Table_A as a string. The first use of `(DT_STR,3,1252)` simply sets the destination column as a `string` so as not to use the same data type as the source which in my case was `int`.

Its the 2nd use of `(DT_STR,3,1252)` that actually casts Column_A from `int` to a `string`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to do all the work in SQL if you aren't doing anything else with that number.

```
select right(cast(ColA as varchar(20)),3) from tableA 
-- you can add another cast if you want it to be an int
```

use that in an execute sql to result set = single row.

Map that to a variable.

In a derived column in data flow you can set that variable to the new column.